No able to bind material located in another file in USDA
I am having issue while binding a material for a mesh when the material is not located in another file
main.usda
#usda 1.0
(
    metersPerUnit = 1
    upAxis = Z
)

def Scene
{
     def "Materials"
     {
       def "MaterialA"{...}
       def "MaterialB"{...}
     }
     
     def Mesh "mesh_model" (
        prepend references = @mesh_model.usda@<Scene>
     ){...} 
}

mesh_model.usda
def "Scene"
{
     def Mesh "my_mesh_model"
     {
        faceVertexCounts=[]
        faceVertexIndices=[] 
        normals=[]

        def GeomSubset "GeomSubset0"
        {
           ...
           rel material:binding = </Scene/Materials/MaterialA>
        }

        def GeomSubset "GeomSubset0"
        {
           ...
           rel material:binding = </Scene/Materials/MaterialB>
        }

     }
}

In this example the model is correctly displayed in my scene, I can also see different group of GeomSubset but none of the material is applied.
tried in omniverse and usdview also, is there any solution for me to apply a material that is not located in another file.
I tried to set both of my materials and mesh in the same file and it worked, but in my project i need both to be separated and the geomsubset should be with the mesh.
